# web scraping in powershell not working anymore

Tags: powershell

The following site used to open fine in IE but now does not show the summary section.  But if I open it up in chrome it does.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022887/title#!%2Fen-us%2Fhelp%2F4022887%2Ftitle%22

I had the following code working using powershell 5 (till some sort of system change here at work)

```
$web ="https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022887/title#!/en-us/help/4022887/title"
$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.silent = $true
$ie.navigate($web)
while($ie.busy){ sleep 1 }
$result = $ie.document.body.getElementsByClassName("kb-summary-section") | select -ExpandProperty innertext
$ie.quit()
```

but as it is using IE via com nothing is getting returned to $result.  I have tried Invoke-WebRequest but again that does not return the desired results.  I suspect it is still using the IE engine.  so my question is does anyone now of a way to scrape the above url for the summary section using chrome's browser features in powershell or maybe even a pure .net route that will go below whatever restrictions / limitations that have been put in place on our IE environment??

Edit 
I still get information in $ie.document.body (dont know how to attach a document to show what i get and it is too long to paste) :(  Like I said it was working in IE and in chrome the site displays correctly but in IE it is missing the summary part

Comment: are you saying IE physically does not show anything? Seems like that would be a browser issue not a powershell issue. What happens when u physically navigate to the site yourself using IE?

Comment: Your suspicion that `Invoke-WebRequest` uses IE under the covers is wrong: `Invoke-WebRequest` issues a direct HTTP request and does not automate any browser. This is also why you can't use it to retrieve the page: the page is built using JavaScript and will not contain the summary text if you download it as plain HTML. The whole IE automation thing is necessary to get around this. If you can't get the page to display correctly in IE, your scraping efforts are most likely doomed to failure, because you can't automate Chrome anywhere near as easily. Ask your admins about the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to of self healed and whatever restrictions that were in place are no longer there (an apparently there have been no changes according to our admin team )  My code is working again via com and I can scrape the site again :).  Thank you to everyone who looked at this.